# My datas(From my LocalDB) doesn't show on my ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hello I have good understanding on C and got a job for C# project but my knowledge on C# is poor. I started a project on C#. Project is billing and accounting software for resturants. I started doing login system. I used MSSQLocalDb.

In my login page i used ComboBox for UserID
[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgyFh.png)
When i click ComboBox it is empty
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaj6E.png)

My youtube teacher's comboBox(Right one):
[Right One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi0y9.png)

I don't know where is the problem please help dev friends...

I tried changing connection string didn't work

My connection code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Adisyon01
{
    internal class cGenel
    {
        //public string conString = ("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Restaurant2;Trusted_Connection=true");
        public string conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Kerem Serinkan\\Restaurant2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        public int _personelId;
    }
}
```

My entry control code:

```
public bool personelEntryControl(string password,int UserId)
{
    bool result = false;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gnl.conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id=@Id AND PASSWORD=@password0", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;

    try
    {
      if(con.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
           
        }
        result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string hata = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }

    return result;
}
```

My SqlDataReader code:

```
public void personelGetbyInformation(ComboBox cb)
{
    cb.Items.Clear();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gnl.conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employee", con);
    


    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        
        con.Open();
       
    }
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        cPersoneller p = new cPersoneller();
        p._personelId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
        p._personelGorevId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TASKID"]);
        p._personelAd = Convert.ToString(dr["NAME"]);
        p._personelSoyad= Convert.ToString(dr["SURNAME"]);
        p._personelParola= Convert.ToString(dr["PASSWORD"]);
        p._personelKullaniciAdi = Convert.ToString(dr["NICKNAME"]);
        p._personelDurum = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["STATUS"]);
        cb.Items.Add(p);
    }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You have to use the debugger to see what is happening when you call this code, inspect the variables on each line stop.  If your code actually reaches `cd.Items.Add(p);` then something else is wrong we can't see.

Comment: And should you be assigning the connection object to the command object _before_ you've verified that the connection is open? This seems contrary to most patterns these days (e.g. that use `using` blocks that don't require you to check if they're open, close them when you're done, etc.).

Comment: Your code almost implies you are storing plain text passwords; I *really* hope for both you and (more importantly) your users you aren't.

Comment: I would suggest you look into the USING statement. The way this is coded your connection pool is going to get filled up and you won't be able to get a connection. And I will second that passwords in clear text is dreadful....borderline criminal.

Comment: Do you call the personelGetbyInformation method anywhere? It isn't shown in your code example. But I would ask why you want to have a dropdown of all available users. That would negate at least half of the security of entering a username/password combination. It would be ridiculous if you have 1,000 users.

Comment: I guess you have verified that the employee table actually has any content?

Comment: You have a typo in the personelEntryControl SQL command - should be password, not password0 (it isn't related to the combo box problem, but you won't get the login to work)

Comment: @Stuckat1337 Can you explain your answer, I'm newbie :( I also debugged and found out i cant connect to server.

Comment: @LarsTech I debugged and found out i can't connect to server. I also tried this string too = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Restaurant2;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: @nepdev Yes it's not empty.

Comment: You should be looking at the exception for "why" it can't connect to the server.  Also, do you have permissions to that file path: `C:\\Users\\Kerem Serinkan` ?

Comment: @LarsTech I debugged it and found these https://www.linkpicture.com/q/1_1474.png  https://www.linkpicture.com/q/2_910.png  https://www.linkpicture.com/q/3_350.png